# How to change tab bar icon programmatically in React Native from another component?

Tags: react-native, tabs, bottomnavigationview

I want to change the bottom tab icon from my home screen or another component. I don't know how to achieve it, in Android I can use `interface` and `EventBus` but I'm not sure there something equivalent in `React-Native`, I tried using `redux store` but didn't work for me I have 5 buttons in the bottom tab bar I want to change the the centre button when I have some check fulfilled from the backend in my home screen.How can I change it from the home screen? any help will be appriciated thank you in advance
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ref` to access method of other component.

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation

EDIT:

Sorry for the late reply, the ref method works best if both components are siblings.

Here see this code:

```
class TestPage1 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state={}

};

onDoSomething=()=>{
this.comp2_ref.callThisMethod()
}
render() {
  return (
      <View>
        <Comp1 onDoSomething={this.onDoSomething}/>
        <Comp2  onRef={(ref)=>{
          this.comp2_ref=ref;
        })/>
      </View>
  )
}
}

class Comp1 extends Component{
render(){
return(<View>
  <Button onPress={()=>{
    typeof 
 this.props.onDoSomething==='function'&&this.props.onDoSomething()
  }}></Button></View>)
 }

}
class Comp2 extends Component{
callThisMethod=()=>{
 //do something for comp2 that will be called by comp 1
}
render(){
return(<View></View>)
}
 componentDidMount(){
  typeof this.props.onRef==='function'&&this.props.onRef(this);
 }

 }
```

If they are separate then you can also use consumer and provider concept.

Comment: thank you for the response however could you please show me usage of this ref, I am new in React-Native can't even work properly with states, so I don't think this `ref` will be easy for me (I tried reading about ref already but didn't understand this)